# make a decision based on response of webhook in mautic

Tags: python, mautic

I was wondering if there is any way to make decisions based on webhook responses in Mautic. To elaborate, I post a request via webhook and the corresponding API responds with an error (e.g. 411). I want to create a campaign that has a block depending on the response of that webhook if it receives 200 decision 1 is made and if it receives 411, another decision is made.

how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such feature exists by default, but there can be alternative ways to do this.

1. sending an api call from the system in question(like on success make a call do set some tag or field) same goes for error. However this is practical as long as you have control over that system.
2. Create a custom campaign Decision node which will listen to the responses of the webhook(in this case you will need to send the webhook using campaign only), Again the block here is that you will need to know how to code a custom campaign decision or will need to look for a developer who can do it.